# ng-lb command in StrongLoop fails when using local-storage-connector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

Dear Strongloop community
I am following the example provided by loopback for evaluating local-storage data store. 
It works fine and I can use the rest API to create and retrieve files from the local file system (used as a data source).
I had to used "$ npm install loopback-component-storage --save".

the datasource defined in datasource.json is:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "localFileSystemStorage": {
    "name": "localFileSystemStorage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./property_data"
  }
}
```

the `./property_data` directory is where all the data is stored. (relative to the project directory) and I can access it through rest with no issues.

Next I was trying to generate Angular service component so I can connect to the loopback server using Angular application. So inside the client directory I executed:

```
../example-2.0/client$  lb-ng  ../server/server.js js/lb-services.js
```

**and it failed:**

```
/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/providers/filesystem/index.js:25
    throw new Error('FileSystemProvider: Path does not exist: ' + this.root);
          ^
Error: FileSystemProvider: Path does not exist: ./server/storage
    at new FileSystemProvider (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/providers/filesystem/index.js:25:11)
    at Object.module.exports.createClient (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/providers/filesystem/index.js:17:10)
    at Object.createClient (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/factory.js:86:18)
    at new StorageService (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/storage-service.js:29:25)
    at Object.exports.initialize (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/storage-connector.js:12:19)
    at DataSource.setup (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:332:17)
    at new DataSource (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:109:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:349:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:415:19)
    at EventEmitter.app.dataSource (/home/eval/projects/loopback-component-storage/example-2.0/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:222:12)
```

**Am I missing something?**
I could really use some help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `datasource.json` file you have provided the relative path `./property_data` with respect to `/server` folder.

Thus you need to call any method from that folder only.

Now when you are running it through the server then you are running it from `/server` folder thats why it runs without an issue but for angular Sdk generation you are doing it from `client/` folder. Thus its genetating `Path does not exist` error.

Thus the correct syntax would be:

```
 ../example-2.0/server$  lb-ng  server.js ../client/js/lb-services.js
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, That was almost correct.
The ./property_data is located under the main project directory so the correct syntax I used following your answer was: </br>

lb-ng  server/server.js client/js/lb-services.js